# ASP.NET MVC and HTML5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have been looking into HTML5 and I am really excited to try it out.
As a framework I would like to use ASP.NET MVC, but I am unsure how it works with HTML5.

Are there (i know there are, but not sure if they are good) any good HTML5 toolkits for ASP.NET MVC? Basically i would like some pointers where to start with creating a page with rich HTML5 controls using MVC + some pros and cons from your experience.

Anyway I am willing to ditch PHP and start with MVC if the HTML support is there... I have C# skills and I understand the MVC pattern.

With best regards, no9.

Comment: You write HTML5 like simple HTML in the views (.cshtml). As for the toolkits I recommend finding which control you like to use and searching for an HTML5 library that has it. You can find almost anything if you know what you are looking for.

Comment: thats the problem, atm I dont know what I am looking for. I just want to use MVC and HTML5 controls

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MVC and HTML 5 don't really have anything to do with each other so you can use any framework you want, its all about the program.

And Visual Studio 2012 supports HTML 5 you should install a extension for VS called "[Web Essentials 2012](http://vswebessentials.com/)" for the best support for HTML 5.

For a good startup you can also check [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) out.

I hope this helps getting you started.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an HTML5 toolkit for ASP.NET MVC that you simply add to your project that will give you the functionality that you need.

Once you have added the library to your project, you can use it in your View like so:

```
@Html.Html5TextBox("txtOne", InputType.Color)
```

Which will return a textbox element that looks like:

```
<input type="color" id="txtOne" name="txtOne">
```

There is loads of support for many other HTML5 input types - for more information, check out the [blog post](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/asp-net-mvc-html5-toolkit/29).